# JS validation doesn't run after I enter a valid input and submit the form with rest of the input fields empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I am developing a web directory with a form on one of its pages. JS validation plug in is used. While submitting the form without filling any Input fields, the form throws errors below each input field as expected! But submitting the form with just one input box filled in refreshes the current page as the action value is set to current page with PHP codes in it, instead of staying on the same page to continue to throw errors for the rest of the fields that are yet to be filled in! I have searched online to find nothing useful in figuring out what is wrong with the script. Could anyone here please look into the code below and recommend the best solution? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $("#userForm").validate({
        rules: {
            cname: {
                required: true,
                lettersonly: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            cemail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            cphone: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 10
            },
            cbusiness: {
                required: true,
                url: true
            },
            cbcategory: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            curl: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
        },
        messages: {
            cname:  "Please enter your name",
            cemail: "Please enter a valid email address",
            cphone: {
                required: "Please enter your phone number",
                number:   "Please enter only numeric value"
            },
            cbusiness: {
                required: "Please enter your business",
                },
            cbcategory: {
                required: "Please enter a business category",
                },
            curl: {
                required: "Please enter the URL to your website",
                },
            }
    });
});
```

The form is as below.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="userForm" id="userForm">

                            <input type="text" name="cname"  id="cname" placeholder=" Your Name">
                            <input type="text" name="cemail" id="cemail" class="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                            <input type="text" name="cphone" id="cphone" placeholder="Your Phone">
                            <input type="text" name="cbusiness"  id="cbusiness" class="email" placeholder=" Your Business">
                            <input type="text" name="cbcategory" id="cbcategory" placeholder="Business category">
                            <input type="text" name="curl" id="curl" class="email" placeholder="URL"><br>       

                            <label for='message'>Enter the code in the box below : </label>
                            <img src="captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" id='captchaimg'>
                            <input type="text" id="captcha_code" name="captcha_code">

                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit"  value="Submit" class="button1"><br>
                Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh.
                        </form>
```

Comment: please edit the question and add _What you want_ and _What you get_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have included the validation libraries corectly, you will have to set messages for all of the validation types like:

```
messages: {
  cname: {
     required: "Please enter your name",
     lettersonly: "Letters only",
     minlength: "Min length 3 required"
  },
  cemail: {
    required: "Please enter a valid email address",
    email: "Invalid email"
  }
}
```

Working **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/y0kugrpn/4/)**.

You have to include the plugin files something like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**:

After discussing with OP on chat, we came to the conclusion that the plugin files had to be included correctly and there was an incompatibility between the jQuery version(v 1.7.1) he used and the plugin version(v 1.16.0). So we had to add a custom method for `lettersonly`.

The code for custom method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters only please");
```

Comment: @lonut, thanks for the suggestions. I have set the messages as advised, yet the issue remains unresolved. For example, when I type in number in the name field, the error message doesn't change from "Please enter a name" to "Letters only". Error messages for all the input fields are seemingly stuck at "Error message for Required". Any advise what else to be done?

Comment: @Pramod, sorry, my mistake. I forgot to add the required options for lettersonly and minlength for the name when I was doing some debugging. I've updated the link to the fiddle in my answer. See now please. You can see that in the jsfiddle it's working. If in your project is not working please check your console for errors.

Comment: @lonut. Thanks a lot. I think we are almost there. I did exactly what you did after having a look at JSFIDDLE. When I entered the numbers in the name field, it didn't throw "Letters only error". Rest of the fields seem to accept what they are meant for.

Comment: @Pramod, you're welcome. Happy to help. You say `I think we are almost there.` So there is something else wrong? Do you need any further help?

Comment: @lonut, yes. I need a bit more of your help with finding out why entering digits in the field meant for name doesn't tigger error message. When I enter '1234' in the first input field for name validation doesn't seem to function. What could be wrong here. Also, please let me know how to use JSFIDDLE to check the validation. I can only see a  form which when submitted throws "Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted".

Comment: @Pramod, hey, check the updated link from my answer to JSFiddle again now. Had to change the Javascript version, because it seemed to cause the problem with 403 forbidden only on Chrome, in Firefox worked fine. Also a link here https://jsfiddle.net/y0kugrpn/4/ This should work now. On the left sidebar of the jsfiddle you can see the external resources from where I added the links to cdn's files of jquery validation plugin. And from the bottom left section you can include jQuery or can set any other JS related options.

Comment: @lonut, You have been a great help. I am 90% successful now with the validation. I see that I need to make sure the error message corresponds to the invalid data user enter. What is happening with name field is that 1.  If enter 2 letters, it says "Please enter your name" instead of min 3.     2. If enter numbers as 123654, it still says "Please enter your name" instead of Letters only".  3. When I enter correct name as Pramod it still shows the message as "Please enter your name". Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Pramod, about the name part, in the jsfiddle it works. I can't replicate the same steps you are saying, it seems to work fine. Make sure as you already said to create coresponding messages for every custom option. Also, please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: @lonut, Console shows some vital error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined     at additional-methods.js:30 and many other. The one that makes sense here is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element cname, check the 'lettersonly' method. I think we should substitute 'lettersonly'  with something else to allow only alphabets.

Comment: This answer does not explain the OP's problem, except maybe forgetting to include the plugin itself.  There was nothing about how the OP declared his `messages` object that would cause the form to do what he claimed.

Comment: @Sparky, you are partially right. But I already came up with a solution discussing on chat with the OP. I'll update it as soon as I can. At first hand the problem was including the plugin files, then realised there was an incompatibility between the version of jQuery he used and the plugin itself.